# How to setting up Xerox DocuPrint M205 b on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, printing, scanner, xerox

Just bought the printer with scanner (copier) capability. Having trouble on setting up the printer/scanner.

Tried to setup with Brother HL 2030
(http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=273489&p=1854278#post1854278)

and,

with Xerox P8e driver
(http://blog.simonrumble.com/fuji-xerox-docuprint-203a-on-ubuntu-linux)

end up with 016-502 error.

The printer come with windows and mac drivers.

Found http://www.fujixeroxprinters.com.au/en/Downloads.aspx?product=8058&category=5726&os=32768&dl=1

Downloaded, but does not know how to do with it yet.

Please help. Thank you

Comment: I've got a call from Xerox Malaysia on Jan 2014 saying that the model does not support Linux. :|

Since it has Scan to / Print From USB storage capability, i have utilizing that features. How ever with a lot of limitation. Some of the USB used, return error when trying to print/scan to. Honestly, a bit annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated my ubuntu (14.04LTS).

1. Installed [foo2zjs](http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/forum/read.php?87,3855,3861)
2. Configure [Postscript-Xerox](http://openprinting.org/driver/Postscript-Xerox)
3. Add printer.

The printer is now working.[image]

Comment: Could you please give some details ?

Comment: @kangear, as for ubuntu 14.04 LTS, i just download and install 
1. [foo2zjs](http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/forum/read.php?87,3855,3861). 
2. Download and install [Postscript-xerox](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/openprinting/database/driverpackages)
3. The configuration in GUI wizard.
Go to "System Settings" , "Printers" , "Add Printer" Follow through the Add Printer Wizard.

Now i am with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. the printer just auto recognized when it is being plugged-in.
(The scanner is not working with pre-installed "Simple Scan" program in the ubuntu)